# How to reshape a tensor in TensorFlowSharp

Tags: c#, tensorflow, tensorflowsharp

**TensorFlowSharp** is the wrapper of **TensorFlow** in c# platform. [click it to jump to **TensorFlowSharp** github](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp)

Now i need to reshape a tensor with shape [32,64,1] into a new tensor with shape [1, 2048].But as i refer to the official API document, the usage seems like that:

```
TFOutput Reshape (TensorFlow.TFOutput tensor, TensorFlow.TFOutput shape);
```

the problem is that i dont know how to express the shape i need in the way of `TFOutput`
Any suggestions will be appreciated:)!

Comment: For the `shape` argument, can you construct a `Constant` of element type `int64` with the values `[1, 2048]` and pass that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard TensorFlowSharp, an example on how to do this operation can be given by:

```
tf.Reshape(x, tf.Const(shape));
```

where `tf` is the current default TFGraph in your TFSession.

Alternatively, if you use Keras Sharp, you might be able to do this operation using

```
using (var K = new TensorFlowBackend())
{
    double[,] input_array = new double[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    Tensor variable = K.variable(array: input_array);
    Tensor variable_new_shape = K.reshape(variable, new int[] { 1, 4 });
    double[,] output = (double[,])variable_new_shape.eval();

    Assert.AreEqual(new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 } }, output);
}
```

as indicated in https://github.com/cesarsouza/keras-sharp/blob/efac7e34457ffb7cf6712793d5298b565549a1c2/Tests/TensorFlowBackendTest.cs#L45

Comment: brilliant! Thanks a lot